# Mock / Simulate hardware in espresso tests

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I'm developing and android app and using Espresso as the auto-test framework.

I've automated the UI related test-cases, but I am stuck at one which needs to read a NFC tag.

Is there any way I can bypass / simulate / mock the NFC ?

I couldn't find anything related to this.